# android merge video and audio on cpu, not gpu

Tags: android, gpu, cpu, video-processing

I merge video with audio using mp4parser library, but when I have files longer then 5-6 mins some devices can't perform this task (actually app stops but not crashes when try to save resulted file on disk). It means UI is frozen, user can't do nothing, but Android doesn't show any messages.

It is performed in asynctask, and the memory level is near 50 Mb (not larger), CPU - up to 20%, but GPU is overloaded.

The problem appears on phones (Moto G(1gen), Moto G(2gen) and Nexus 5). In other hand Nexus 7 can merge video longer then 10 mins without any problem.

Also I have hardware acceleration enabled, but I try to switch it off and it didn't help.

So, is there any way to perform this operation using CPU, not GPU? Thanks a lot.

Comment: mp4parser is a pure Java library. it would slower compare to low level android api. You could use media mixer ape from android